# SQLAlchemy 1.4 yield_per on redshift

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

Using redshift and sqlalchemy 1.4

I'm using yield_per on my query but i'm running into this exception
`psycopg2.errors.InvalidCursorState: opening multiple cursors from within the same client connection is not allowed`

My code looks like this

```
with get_session() as session:
    chunks = session.query(my_model).yield_per(100)
    for chunk in chunks:
        pass
```

The exception is raised on the session.query() line. I have no other sessions open and no other cursors open.

I've checked for active cursors in redshift using `SELECT * FROM STV_ACTIVE_CURSORS`  with no results. so this is creating multiple cursors why?